# Calculus Derivatives - Finding a function, given point and slope

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I am having trouble solving this Calculus TIPS question:

```
1. Let f(x)=ax^2+bx+c. Find a,b and c so that the
tangent to the graph y=f(x) at (1,5) has slope 1 and f(0)=-5.
```

Comment: Hint: We know $c$ quickly! Now take a derivative and evaluate.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

You are given $$f(x)=ax^2+b x+c$$ to which corresponds $$f'(x)=2ax+b$$ You are told that $$f(0)=-5 \qquad f(1)=5 \qquad f'(1)=1$$ So, three simple linear equations in $a,b,c$.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c \implies f'(x) = 2ax+b$$

And of course the slope of the tangent is the derivative, so

$$\begin{align}
1 &= f'(1) \\
1 &= 2a(1) + b \\
1 &= 2a+b \\
\end{align}$$

We also know that $f(0)=-5$, so

$$\begin{align}
f(0) &= a(0)^2+b(0)+c \\
-5 & = c \\
\end{align}$$

Sweet—that was easy!

The problem also tells us, explicitly, that

$$\begin{align}
5 &= f(1) \\
5 &= a(1)^2+b(1)+c \\
5 &= a+b+c \\
\end{align}$$

Thus we are left with a system of equations:

$$\begin{cases}
1=2a+b \\
-5 = c \\
5=a+b+c \\
\end{cases}$$

Which you can convert into a matrix and which you can convert into rref:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -5 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 5 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\Longrightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&-9\\
0&1&0&19\\
0&0&1&-5\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

which implies

$$\begin{align}
a&=-9\\
b&=19\\
c&=-5\\
\end{align}$$

The resultant quadratic checks out with the description in the original problem!

Answer (score 0):

The question has already been answered, I will just try to keep the solution more limited to a junior school level.

So, the given equation is, 
$$
f(x) = ax^2+bx+c \tag*{(1)}
$$
Now, slope of $f(x)$ is given by,

$$
f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}f(x)=2ax+b \tag*{(2)}
$$

According to the question, 
$$
f(x)|_{x=0} = -5\\
\implies a \cdot0^2+b\cdot 0 + c=-5\\
\implies \boxed{\boxed{c=-5}}
$$

Also, it is given that, 
$$
f(x)|_{x=1}=5\\
\implies a \cdot 1^2+b\cdot 1+c=5\\
\implies a+b-5=5\\
\implies \boxed{a+b = 10} \tag*{(3)}
$$

Also, given that the slope when $x=1$ is $1$, therefore, 
$$
f'(x)|_{x=1}=1\\
\implies 2 \cdot a \cdot 1 + b = 1\\
\implies \boxed{2a+b=1} \tag*{(4)}
$$

Noqw, we solve equations $(3)$ and $(4)$, 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
2a + b &= 1\\ 
a + b &= 10\\  
(-) \ (-) & (-) \\
\hline
a &= -9
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Thus, 
$$
\boxed{\boxed{a = -9}}
$$

Similarly, we get 
$$
\boxed{\boxed{b =19}}
$$

Hope this helps!